# EF 4.1 Code First doesn't create column for List<string>

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have been playing around quite a lot with EF4 Code First and I do love it. However, I cannot seem to sort this easy one out.

When trying to create something like this, no columns are created in my database:

```
    public IList<String> Recievers { get; set; }
    public List<String> RecieversTest { get; set; }

    public virtual List<String> RecieversAnotherTest { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Int32> RecieversAnotherTest { get; set; }
```

Ive tried Annotations to map it to a different column name, I've tried IEnumerable and all sorts of other collections, but it refuses to create a column for it.

After an hour on google I found one that claims she has done it, but I'm starting to doubt that. Should it even be possible?

I can't really see why it just doesn't create a column and use JSON or CSV.
It can't be that rare, can it? In my case i just want to store a list of emails.

What am I missing? The project creates all other types without problems, and I've inspected the database to see how other properties I add to test with gets created, while these gets ignored.

So the problem must lie in some setting I'm missing or some configuration....
EF 4.1 RTW on an SQL Server 2008 db.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have bad news for you. EF doesn't do anything like that. If you want any serialization and deserialization you must do it yourselves = you must expose and map property with serialized value:

```
private IList<String> _receivers;
// This will be skipped
public IList<String> Receivers 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _receivers;
    }
    set
    {
        _receivers = value;
    } 
}

// This will be mapped
public string ReceiversSer
{
    get
    {
        return String.Join(";", _receivers);
    }
    set
    {
        _receivers = value.Split(';').ToList();
    }
}
```

Now `ReceiversSer` will be mapped to a column in the database.

Comment: very smart solution... i like how you accomplished that

Comment: @Ladislav-mrnka Great solution. The only problem is that it doesn't handle null references. Replace `_receivers = value.Split(';').ToList();` with `_receivers = value != null ? value.Split(';').ToList() : null;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a column based on a collection/list of something.  A column is a singular item such as `public string Receiver`.

If you are expecting EF CF to take your IList or List and make several Columns out of it you are correct in that it won't.

In EF CF you create lists in your Entity to represent a relationship to another table.  An Order may have many Items in it.  You would in this case have an Order class with a list to an OrderItem object.

You would then have an OrderItem class to describe the OrderItem table.  This would then essentially represent the 1 to many relationship of Order and OrderItems.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm not really convinced about your argument. There is a big difference between a custom class like an order and a string. I'm not expecting EF to create several columns for me, but I am sort of expecting it to serialize my list into an appropriate format, and then deserialize it on fetch. I guess I've become a little spoiled. I can see the potential problem, but considering what EF does in other situations I don't really see any big reason this wouldn't be supported.

Comment: EF has no way of "mapping" just a list of strings to your parent class.  It can map a list of another Entity because of it's built-in configuration or your annotations.... :-)